# How to start flask web in separate thread in Python

Tags: flask

I am working on a pet project  which includes flask web site (Arduino sensor's data is written to the database) and telegram bot (sends sensor's data in case of emergency). Now I have either a bot or a web working.

**framework:**

```
app
    __init__.py
runner.py
config.py
```

****init**.py:**

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config.DevelopementConfig')
app.config.from_object('config.ProductionConfig')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

**runner.py:**

```
import asyncio
import logging

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
from aiogram.enums.parse_mode import ParseMode

import config

async def main():
    bot = Bot(token=config.BOT_TOKEN, parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
    await bot.delete_webhook(drop_pending_updates=True)
    await dp.start_polling(bot, allowed_updates=dp.resolve_used_update_types())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #asyncio.run(main())
    app.run(debug=False)
```

How can I make them work simultaneously?

May be something like this:

```
import threading


if __name__ == "__main__":
    threading.Thread(target=lambda: app.run(debug=False, use_reloader=False)).start()
```

Comment: https://github.com/davewsmith/lapse/blob/main/lapse.py#L31 shows how I did it in an old project. It should still work, though the code to quit the app via the web no longer does.